# How do I convert a mercurial fork into a branch of its parent?

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to convert a big amount of mercurial forks into branches and I am looking for a way to do this.

Is there a script that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a script to do this automatically, but what I would do is this:

- `cd /path/to/fork`
- `hg bookmark name-of-fork`
- `cd /path/to/parent`
- `hg pull /path/to/fork`

Repeat this for all forks, and it will give you each fork with a bookmark on top. Then you can move between the branches in your parent repository with `hg update bookmark-name`, and you can remove all the forks to save disk space by reducing the shared information stored in each separate fork.

You could also use mercurial's branch functionality, but this would require rewriting all commits, and is much more trouble than it's worth (I think the value is mostly negative, actually).

Comment: In fact I do want to transform them in real branches, as I have lots of them to convert, up to 300 forks for each of ~150 repos, to be clear ~22.000 repositories to "compact".

Comment: What advantage do you think named branches will give you? The number of branches doesn't seem relevant to making this choice to me, but it does increase the complexity of the task and it would also require mercurial extensions, etc.

Comment: 1st size, imagine that the number of changes made on each branch is very small compared with the ones made on trunk. Ability to merge code much easier.

Comment: Using the technique I mentioned here will drastically reduce overall size of repos; you do not need named branches to accomplish this. I think we're running into a terminology problem here.

In mercurial, there is a `default` *named* branch which can have many heads (aka, graph branches), although they will all share the same *named* branch name, they will be identifiable with separate bookmarks, and your "parent" repository will have all these as "branches" (ie, when viewed with `hg log --graph`).

Regardless, you don't need to use named branches to get the functionality you want.